# ggplot2 - difference X axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, subplot

[image]

[image]

I would like to create a chart where the choice of two data sources makes the difference between the two on the Y-axis.

I wrote this:

```
ggplot (Values-, aes (x = X, y = (Values $ Y [1] -Values $ Y [2])))
```

but this `(Values $ Y [1] -Values $ Y [2])` makes the difference to me for the first value of the X, but it is the same for all the others.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: You shouldn't use the name of the dataframe inside `ggplot` in places like `aes`. Why is there a minus sign after the name of your dataframe? Beyond that, I can't tell what's going on or what you're trying to do unless you `dput` a sample of your data

Comment: the object d must contain the difference between the 2 bars as you can see in the image.
I did this
   for (i in Values $ Y) {
     Values $ Y [i] = Values $ Y [i + 1] - Values $ Y [i + 2]
   }

but it does not work. alternating with 1 Y contains the values of a type (in total there are 2)

Comment: the second chart must have only one bar and not the 2 colors .. and it must be the difference between the two

Comment: It's still unclear what you're doing or what the problem is without seeing the data, and based on the questions I asked in my earlier comment. You should read through [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on how to make an R question that will be easy for folks to help you with